# Entity Framework query mapping issue

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a weird issues with an EF entity that generates an incorrect query where the query is generating columns that reflect a navigation property mapping. However, I have removed those navigation properties and the query still generates the related columns.
The entity in question is as below...

```
[Table("Order")]
public partial class Order
{

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int? OrderCampaignIDlink { get; set; }
    public int? OrderItemIDlink { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? OrderDateAdded { get; set; }
    public int? OrderStatusIDlink { get; set; }
    public int? OrderSupplierIDlink { get; set; }
}
```

which is mapped via a sub-class of `DbContext`...

```
public partial class Entities3 : DbContext
{
    public Entities3() : base("name=Entities3")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }


    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){...}
 }
```

there's a web api controller that calls on "Orders"...

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrders()
    {
         return await Db.Orders.ToListAsync();
    }
```

which throws the following error...

```
"Invalid column name 'Campaign_CampaignId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Company_CompanyId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'OrderStatus_OrderStatusId'."
```

and finally below is the generate query as reported by SQL Server Profiler...

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
[Extent1].[OrderCampaignIDlink] AS [OrderCampaignIDlink], 
[Extent1].[OrderItemIDlink] AS [OrderItemIDlink], 
[Extent1].[OrderDateAdded] AS [OrderDateAdded], 
[Extent1].[OrderStatusIDlink] AS [OrderStatusIDlink], 
[Extent1].[OrderSupplierIDlink] AS [OrderSupplierIDlink], 
[Extent1].[Campaign_CampaignId] AS [Campaign_CampaignId], 
[Extent1].[Company_CompanyId] AS [Company_CompanyId], 
[Extent1].[OrderStatus_OrderStatusId] AS [OrderStatus_OrderStatusId]
FROM [dbo].[Order] AS [Extent1]
```

As you can see there are some columns in the `select` query that are NOT mapped at all. I used to have some navigation properties before as reflected in the query but I have commented them out.

#### Things I've tried

- Refreshing the internet browser (Ctrl + F5)
- Stopping, restarting the AppPool in IIS

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is in this code: protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){...}

Comment: Have you tried "FINDING" in your project where atleast one of these columns might be referenced? I am guessing that they are being built in to your object some place else. As suggested can you post ModelCreating event code?

Comment: I didn't want to make the question too extensive, but forgot to mention that I removed all references from `OnModelCreating`. Now, I have already found the problem, I'll post the answer later for anyone coming from Google, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'd just leave the answer here for future references. The actually problem is rather simply and silly. I forgot to remove the references to `Orders` on the other side of the relationship. That is, I had a `Campaign` entity that was still holding references to the `Order` entity as below...

```
public class Campaign
{
    public Campaign()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set; }
}
```

same with a `Company` entity that had a collection of `Order` entities. EF was expecting a foreign key relationship on the `Order` entity. Either removing that (to remove the relationship) or adding the respective `Campaign` and `Company` navigation properties with the respective foreign key to the `Order` entity (to reflect the proper one-to-many relationship) should get rid of the error.